# HTML - Why isn't indeterminate="indeterminate|true" respected?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I want to use the indeterminate property of a checkbox. Changing the value in JavaScript works in all sorts of browsers (even MSIE6!), however, I cannot set the initial value via HTML attributes in *any*.

Is this by design? **If so, why?** On server side, I can determine that it's indeterminate. So, why can't I tell the browser? Weren't browser vendors worried about FOUCs (Flashes Of Unstyled Content) if a long-running script holds up the property-setting?

Here's a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/KUQC9/1/

Comment: What's the `indeterminate` property?

Comment: @Rocket, look at the working example.

Comment: I'm just learning about this now. I have a question for you, actually... you said you can determine that it's indeterminate on the server: how do you do that? (By the way, you could largely avoid FOUCs by using the DOM-load event rather than a timeout - http://jsfiddle.net/Cd35L/ - or even sooner - http://jsfiddle.net/dV3uL/ )

Comment: I had a tree construct stored on the server. I basically restored the state from the last time the form containing nested checkboxes was submitted. That is, while building the form, if a node was unchecked previously, I recurse the tree looking for any checked children. If any children are checked, the parent is indeterminate. Regarding the FOUCs, my tree was somewhat large -- any larger and I would've been concerned w/the possibility of a FOUC.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can't make a checkbox indeterminate through HTML by design.  See this article on [css-tricks.com](http://css-tricks.com/indeterminate-checkboxes/), which discusses the topic in depth.

As for the "why" part of your question, there is some information on the W3C mailing lists that may be helpful:

- It looks as if the idea of giving checkboxes a tri-state value (seemingly checked, unchecked, indeterminate) was considered, but not implemented because of backwards-compatibility issues

  - [See this message](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-dom/2002JanMar/0015.html)
  - [And the response](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-dom/2002JanMar/0018.html)
- The only mention of a true `indeterminate` HTML "content" attribute, as you show in your example, that I could find was here:

  - [In this message](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-dom/2002JanMar/0141.html)
  - [And the response](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-dom/2002JanMar/0146.html)
  - You might try contacting those involved in that thread for more information

For what it's worth, there is in fact an `:indeterminate` CSS selector (it seems to be treated like other CSS pseudo-classes like `:visited`, which also cannot be set through HTML directly, so maybe that is another reason `indeterminate` can't be either).  In its demo of the CSS selector the W3C itself uses about the same approach that you do: [W3C indeterminate CSS selector demo](http://www.w3.org/Style/CSS/Test/CSS3/Selectors/20040510/html/full/flat/css3-modsel-d5.html).  In light of that, I'd say you're using about the best method available for setting the indeterminate state of a check box

Comment: The article nor its comments really discuss the why.

Comment: @Olson.dev: I added a little information from the W3C mailing lists- see my edits. Hopefully it is of some value to you- good luck!

Comment: thanks. I found those links helpful regarding the "why" and have marked your answer accepted. Also +1.

Answer (score 4):

It is by design.  The only HTML way to denote checkbox state is through the checked attribute; this is because checkbox is meant to true/false, rather than true/false/unknown.  Marking something indeterminate can be done via Javascript, but it will not change the actual/sumbitted value of the checkbox.

If you really want to initialize checkboxes to indeterminate, you'll need to do it with Javascript (I would imagine on the load event).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, you didn't tell me much more than I specified in the question. Whose design? Why is it this way? I understand it's meant to be true/false but not unknown, which is why I proposed 2 separate attributes (just how the properties are separate). Also, my working example already shows initializing them via JavaScript.

Comment: It is the design of the w3c (http://w3.org), the body that formally recognizing/codifies/designs HTML.  HTML (and XHTML and, for that matter, XML) are document languages, rather than programming languages.  If the purpose within the document of a checkbox is to designate an option which must either be true or false, what purpose would having an attribute that describes that true/false value as unknown serve.

Comment: Son of a . . . according to the w3c's Feb 16 2012 draft of HTML5, it indeterminate is an attribute of the input element.  
http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/the-input-element.html#dom-input-indeterminate
Cannot initially be set (to true).

Comment: @post_erasmus: That is the **IDL** attribute that OP is already referencing- they are just now getting around to officially adding it to the spec. There is still no **content** (HTML) attribute `indeterminate` that I am aware of.

Comment: @JackieChiles: Absolutely true.  And even once added to spec, who knows how long before it will be implemented in the major browsers?  I wanted to point it out as a few seconds before I'd told that it wasn't part of the spec/didn't belong in HTML.

Comment: Updated link @devstruck : https://w3c.github.io/html/sec-forms.html#checkbox-state-typecheckbox